# SPD-SL pedals uneven wear

Tags: shimano, pedals, wear

I have been riding my road bike for about 10k km on those pedals (shimano ultegra spd-sl) and it just so happened that the left one is now worn much more than the right one (check out photos).  You should look at the spring/cramp/lock (whatever the right word is:) ) part of the pedal, that black thing which doesn’t let the cleats pop out. Now my left pedal almost can’t hold the cleat in when pedaling , had to tighen it close to the max limit. It still holds but I don’t think it will last long. The right one, on the other hand, still does it perfectly and is almost not worn at all, after even that distance (there is no play/looseness, never tightened it yet).

Any advice would be nice! Such wear on the left pedal – did I gauged it right that the end is nigh for it? How much more can it last possibly? Is it real to by one separate pedal  (not necessarily ultegra)? Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: So, which one to you unclip when you stop for a traffic light?

Comment: Cleaning the pedals and the cleats from time to time reduces wear. Also if I unclip and put the foot down I always try to touch down with the heel only. And I take care not to put the foot in sand or mud. Cleat protector covers are handy for walking (short) distances.

Comment: You should have a good look for spare *parts* for the pedal -- I don't have enough information to figure out exactly what you need but some bits are available at least for cheaper pedals like mine.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I feel like there's a joke here - 10,000 kilometers?

Comment: @jqning - 10,000 km is on a pair of pedals is easily believable.  Some people do that in a year, many would rack up that much in 5-10 years.

Comment: @DanielRHicks In fairness, I've never used a pedal with plastic parts, so I didn't know they should last that many miles of normal use. I certainly wouldn't expect it.

Comment: @jqning - I don't think they're plastic parts.

Comment: @DanielRHicks composite something. I guess the cleat is made of the same stuff so that should slow the wear. I also just realized this is an old question.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - the wear rare is crazy.  I have gotten far more than 10,000 km out of the exact same pedals entirely on muddy gravel tracks.  My pedals are often covered in debris. While I have some wear, nothing to this extent. I wonder if there are some incredibly abrasive materials in the OP's environment.

Comment: It may well be that the left side shoe has never been latching in properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to completely disassemble a pair of old pedal clips, looking vaguely similar to yours. If they are not handed, then you could simply reassemble them with the most worn clip on the other side.

This may not be viable if the clip is worn to the point of not working any more.   Essentially the same idea as rotating the tyres on a car, swapping front for back to even out the tread wear.